# Spread operator (...) does not work for spreading widgets from a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of widgets which is to be spread across the children attribute of Column. Tried using the spread operator, but it gives error.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home : Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("My First Flutter App"),
            ),
          body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(
              questions[counter]['questionText'],
            ),
            ...(questions[counter]['answers'] as List<String>)
                .map((answer) {
              return Answer(answer,answered);
            }).toList()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: "Expected an identifier"

Comment: On the same line where the spread operator (...) is present

Comment: Can you please provide the exact error that's output? It's not obvious what your issue is and a simple reproduction case works.

Comment: "Expected an identifier" - It s showing only this. There spread operator (...) is underlined with red

Comment: What version of Flutter are you using?

Comment: post the output of `flutter --version` command

Comment: Flutter 1.14.6 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision fabeb2a16f (10 days ago) • 2020-01-28 07:56:51 -0800
Engine • revision c4229bfbba
Tools • Dart 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.5.0 fc3af737c7)

Comment: P.S I'm using VS Code

Comment: ok just for testing, uncomment your `Question` and list of `Answer`s and try: `Text('1'), ...[Text('2'), Text('3')]` - is `...` on red too?

Comment: yes. not only the ```...``` but also the ```,``` between ```Text('2')``` and ```Text('3')``` is also red

Comment: Pasted [this code](https://gist.github.com/andrewackerman/c9d680a163ca308f458864a8639d83f1)  into DartPad and it works as expected. The issue may be with your setup, or perhaps your linter is bugged out. Try closing and reopening VS Code, or check elsewhere in your code to see if there's an orphaned bracket or something somewhere. If nothing else, try switching to the `stable` channel of Flutter.

Comment: ```body: Text('foo'),``` is working fine.

Comment: I checked, there are no unbalanced brackets

Answer (score 3):

3 steps to follow 
 1)run "flutter upgrade"
 2) changing the SDK in the environment in pubspec.yaml
      environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"
             OR
      environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
save the file

3)restart Your IDE(Visual Studio or Android Studio)